# Is there a way to hide all notifications during the night?

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, notification-bar, sleep

I mean something like this:

[image]

I'd like to hide them like this during "downtime period" or "do not disturb mode".
I'd like to hide them both on the lock screen on the status bar at the top of the screen.

## Background

I'm interested in something like this because I like not to be disturbed around bedtime, or when I wake up during the night and glance at the screen to check current time.

For example: today morning I woke up ahead of time, very much not refreshed, and when I went to check for time on my phone, I saw a notification which got me excited and unable to fall back asleep. It's situations like this that I'd like to avoid.

*[Source for the picture](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-l-preview-do-not-disturb-mode). I presume the notification-hiding functionality might not have made its way into Lollipop -- since I haven't seen it in settings. Or has it?*

#### Any ideas?

Comment: Ermm, I'm not sure if it hasn't made its way into Lollipop, since the feature is there on Lollipop: Settings - Sound & notification - Interruptions - Downtime. Is that what you missed?

Comment: I've already tried downtime settings, but as far as I can tell in Android  5.1.1, downtime only affects sounds of notifications, and not how they are displayed on the lock screen. Am I mistaken? Even if I am not, thanks for the tip. The way I see it, this functionality would be a nice (probably optional) extension to the existing downtime settings.

Comment: I see, my bad, I never use downtime, so I don't know that it doesn't hide notification. Interesting question, since it can also be used to make the lock screen tidier.

Comment: If you don't use downtime, may I ask how you sleep at night? Are you not disturbed by the noises your phone might make? Or do you set it to silent manually every day before going to bed?

Comment: I always use vibrate-only, except when I'm waiting for something very important that I need to turn on the ringer volume, so... that's it :/

Comment: I've been looking for something like this for ages. Have you found a solution by now, Wizek?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an app called
[Notifications off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff). 
(Root required )

It has a settings that lets you block notifications at night.

[image: Notifications off]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, the app says it needs superuser privileges. Do I need to root my device (therefore voiding warranty?) in order to make this app work?

Comment: @Wizek yeah, from the app description: "*ROOT is required for the app to work.*".